# SSL Certification works inconsistently (NGINX)

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, digital-ocean, certbot

I am using Certbot with NGINX on a Digital Ocean droplet to serve various subdomains. The subdomains on my local machine (chrome, safari, and firefox) and on my friends machine (chrome and firefox) are accessed securely, but they aren't secure on my phone or other people's machines (chrome, safari). How can I make the domain and subdomains consistently secure?

The domains are the following:

- joshkaiser.dev (Expected: 502)
- survivops.joshkaiser.dev (Expected: A half-finished website)
- sortvisualizer.joshkaiser.dev (Expected: A bar graph)

I assume something is wrong with my NGINX configuration, but I can't figure out what.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Here is my johskaiser.dev.conf in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server http2;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on http2;   
    server_name joshkaiser.dev www.joshkaiser.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server http2;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on http2;
    
    server_name joshkaiser.dev www.joshkaiser.dev;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/joshkaiser.dev/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/joshkaiser.dev/privkey.pem;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    }
}


# Survivops

server {
        listen 80 http2;
        server_name survivops.joshkaiser.dev;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        server_name survivops.joshkaiser.dev;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/joshkaiser.dev/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/joshkaiser.dev/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        }
}


# Sort Visualizer

server {
        listen 80 http2;
        server_name sortvisualizer.joshkaiser.dev;
    
    root /var/www/sortvisualizer.joshkaiser.dev;

    index index.html;
    
        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        server_name sortvisualizer.joshkaiser.dev;

    root /var/www/sortvisualizer.joshkaiser.dev;

    index index.html;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/joshkaiser.dev/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/joshkaiser.dev/privkey.pem;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

These are my certificates:

```
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: joshkaiser.dev
    Serial Number: 37d86e384e3b1ad3b0aadb29618f4411683
    Domains: joshkaiser.dev *.joshkaiser.dev
    Expiry Date: 2020-12-20 21:57:41+00:00 (VALID: 87 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/joshkaiser.dev/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/joshkaiser.dev/privkey.pem
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your server setup, __likely outside of the nginx config you show__. It returns a strange 57 byte binary message when connecting to IPv4 and IPv6 port 80 and IPv6 port 443 - only IPv4 port 443 works with the expected HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you! Could you share what tools/ commands you used to find that out so I can use them to debug the issue?

Comment: telnet and `openssl s_client` with option `-4` vs. `-6` etc. Nothing special.